# database table is getting emptied on phpmyadmin automatically,randomly

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, is-empty, mysql5

My database table on `phpmyadmin` is being automatically emptied periodically. Sometimes  all the data is getting deleted after 2-3 days, sometimes it takes weeks to get emptied. I didn't find any solution to this problem on google. I am using Mysql5.

If there's anymore information you need to solve this problem, let me know in the comments. Can anyone kindly tell me about how can I solve this problem?

Comment: No one will be able to answer your question with this information.

Comment: Can u kindly suggest what else information should i provide?

Comment: I really can't. This is just too complex of a question to be answered by Stack Overflow. You're talking about troubleshooting an entire environment, not just a single query or function. It's like asking a mechanic on the internet why your car is making a strange sound when you drive, there's a million things that could be wrong.